# Factory pattern for child classes with changing parameter/ return types in virtual functions

Tags: c++, generics, design-patterns, factory

I would like to write a factory for classes which essentially only differ in the type of message they process, but otherwise are completely the same. I thought about writing a child class and let them inherit from it to have a common ancestor. Since the message types the children have to handle differ, I thought about using a template class as common ancestor, pretty much like in the following example.

```
template <typename T>
class Parent 
{
public:
  virtual void Set(T message); 
  virtual T Get();
}

class ChildA : public Parent<MessageType_A>
{
public:
  void Set( MessageType_A message);
  MessageType_A Get(); 
private:
  MessageType_A mMessage;
}

class ChildB : public Parent<MessageType_B>
{
public:
  void Set( MessageType_B message);
  MessageType_B Get(); 
private:
  MessageType_B mMessage;
}
```

However, due to the template in the parent, I don't have a common base class to use for the factory and can't think of a way to solve the problem.
I was thinking of using std::any, unions or variants but these introduce only more obstacles to my problem instead of solving them.
Would anyone have an idea of how I could create a factory with my described requirements?

Comment: you can always add another (non-template) common base class, question is just how useful is it, when the different classes do not share any common interface

Comment: How do you expect to use (unrelated) `ChildA`/`ChldB`?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: The lack of common interfaces unfortunately won't work for me.

Comment: @Jarod42: That's the problem I was hoping to solve with a common parent

Comment: the lack of common interface is what you have currently. My doubt is the same as Nathans. Suppose you could write a factory function, how would you use it? `??what type?? x = factory(x,y,z);`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: That's exactly why I ask for suggestions to solve that problem. In my question I was already trying to explain it's not going to work with a template class parent since it is not a common ancestor anymore.

Comment: yeah I understand that. But without more context, the best suggestion I can give is to acutally make them inherit from a common ancestor (see answer)

Comment: I would argue that what you seem to regard as a minor difference is really an essential difference that makes these types only vaguely related at best.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Unfortunately I cannot create a common ancestor for the message types. I will have to send the messages as byte strings and the recipient would them assume the wrong size since they use the message types without common ancestor, too

Comment: "I will have to send the messages as byte strings" this seems to be the common interface. If what is common to all messages is that you can get some `char*`  and size from them then that is what belongs in the common base class. If they have really nothing in common a factory cant help

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option for me, since then I would have to continuously work on streams instead of the deserialized  class member variables, since the stream would be the only parameter I could use in the virtual functions.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you misunderstood. The answer I wrote before you said you need a bufffer and size from the messages. With this new information, I am not suggesting you to use the interface as I wrote in the answer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Different instantiations of `Parent` are different unrelated types.

> I thought about using a template class as common ancestor

There is no common ancestor to `ChildA` and `ChildB`. One inherits from `Parent<MessageType_A>` the other from `Parent<MessageType_B>`.

Reconsider if you can make all `ChildX` have a common interface. Just as an example, consider the messages are read from an istream and written to an ostream, then a common interface could look like this:

```
struct Common {
    virtual void In(std::istream&) = 0;
    virtual void Out(std::ostream&) = 0;
};
```

`Parent` would then be

```
template <typename T>
class Parent : public Common
{
public:
  void In(std::istream& in) {
      T t;
      in >> t;
      Set(t);
  }
  void Out(std::ostream& out) {
      out << Get();
  }
protected:
  virtual void Set(T message);
  virtual T Get();
}
```

Now you can inherit different `ChildX` from different `Parent<T>` and they all have a common ancestor `Common`.